# Is there a concept of server-side cookies in ASP.NET?

Tags: cookies, server-side

Not sure if I am missing a basic ASP.NET concept here, but is there a concept of server-side cookies. I know how a HTTPCookie is created on server and sent to client. But are server-side cookies something which allow to use cookies even if the client disables cookies?

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET has a concept of the session object.  It should store a small bit of information whether or not the user has cookies enabled.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx

Comment: Yup that is the way to go. A colleague of mine just approached me and asked if I knew about server-side cookies and I had a big question mark on my face. I do not think the term "server-side cookie" makes sense at all :).

Comment: agreed, what would server side cookies be for? how could you link them with the current user?

Comment: Yup, I just clarified to my colleague that he is an idiot. 
Thanks guys.

Comment: Haha.. Maybe not an idiot, but he is at least confused on his terminology. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatives for storing data on the server exist. 
I use session state. Stores information on the server regarding the current user

http://www.dotnetjunkies.com/quickstart/aspplus/doc/stateoverview.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are stored in memory, this is on the client side.

When the server receives a page hit, you can set a session variable - but not a *cookie* per se.

Cookies are client side and don't manage to make it to the server side.

But if anybody knows of any concept regarding server side cookies, let me know as well.